# Why use Phi(m) divide Order(p, m) to get slot number in HElib?

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, number-theory

I am reading [HElib](https://github.com/shaih/HElib) source code, and have a confusion about [FindM](https://github.com/shaih/HElib/blob/533ad3982379a5cab73162818a7dc88a90fd4e49/src/FHEContext.cpp#L18) function:

```
static long ms[][4] = {  // pre-computed values of [phi(m),m,d]
  //phi(m), m, ord(2),c_m*1000 (not used anymore)
  { 1176,  1247, 28,  3736}, // gens=5(42)
  ......
};
for (i=0; i<sizeof(ms)/sizeof(long[4]); i++) { 
  if (ms[i][0] < N || GCD(p, ms[i][1]) != 1) continue;
  long ordP = multOrd(p, ms[i][1]);
  long nSlots = ms[i][0]/ordP;
  if (d != 0 && ordP % d != 0) continue;
  if (nSlots < s) continue;

  m = ms[i][1];
  break;
}
```

What I can't understand is why use `Phi(m)` to divide `Order(p, m)` to get the slot number? Is there special requirement of getting slot number?

Comment: I know that if the m-th cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_m(x)$ factors mod $p$, then, it is a product of polynomials of equal degree (let's say, this degree is $d$). Also, the degree of $\Phi_m(x)$ is $\varphi(m)$. Therefore, if $\Phi_m(x)$ is a product of $k$ polynomials, we have that $k = \frac{\varphi(m)}{d}$. So, what remains here is to check why $d$ equals Order(p,m)... Note the $k$ is the number of slots.